# Can composer display git commits while in stable mode?

Tags: composer-php, version, updates, git-commit

When running `composer update -v` in a project with `"minimum-stability": "dev"`, we can see the latest commits to the package being updated:

```
composer update -v
...
Extracting archive  - Updating organization/project (v1.0.0 => v1.0.1):  Checking out hash3
    Pulling in changes:
      hash3 - Contributor #1: Improve service
      hash2 - Contributor #2: Improve SQL query
      hash1 - Contributor #3: Hotfix service
```

This is helpful because it gives us some hints on what code was changed.

However, now that our project is in `"minimum-stability": "stable"` mode, when running `composer update -v`, we can no longer see the latest commits to the package being updated:

```
composer update -v
...
Updates: organization/project:v1.0.2
 - Updating organization/project (v1.0.1 => v1.0.2): Downloading (100%)
```

No git commits are shown. We have tried using `composer update -vv` and `composer update -vvv` to no avail.

Therefore, is it possible to still show git commits when updating a package while in stable mode?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One possible solution is to delete all installed packages in the `/vendor` directory, and then re-install them using:

```
composer install --prefer-source
```

All of the same packages will be installed along with their respective `.git` directories.

Then, the next time you run

```
composer update -v
```

since the `.git` directory exists for each package, you will see the latest commits that are pulled in.

However, this solution would not work in a production environment in which deleting files in the `/vendor` directory, even temporarily, would not be an option.